# Нужно ли тире перед союзом "и" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, и

*Используй воображение — и у тебя всё получится.*

Нужно ли тире или запятая перед союзом "и" в данном предложении?

Answer (score 2):

***Используй воображение — и у тебя всё получится.***

Тире в сложносочиненном предложении (ССП)  является **неосновным знаком**, поэтому во многих случаях это **авторское** решение. В устной речи в этом случае делается увеличенная пауза.

Обычно в правилах указываются факторы, влияющие на постановку тире. Это тире можно назвать разделительным, оно делит предложение на **две фразы, противопоставленные друг друг**у (интонация восходяще-нисходящая).

**Это бывает необходимо** при противопоставлении и резком переходе, при разной структуре частей (чтобы обозначить их), при делении на две смысловые части. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Что может оправдать **постановку тире** в заданном предложении?

**Разная структура** отчасти присутствует: у нас односоставное и двусоставное предложение, и этот фактор оказывает влияние на постановку тире.

Но в большей степени это обозначение **подчеркнутого условно-следственного отношения** между простыми предложениями: ***Если будешь использовать воображение, то у тебя всё получится.***

Answer (score 1):

**Используй воображение — и у тебя всё получится.**

В этом сложносочиненном предложении между предикативными частями, соединенными союзом **и**, существуют условно-следственные отношения.
[*Ты*] *Используй воображение* — сказуемое имеет форму повелительного наклонения со значением условия (подлежащее пропущено); *у тебя всё получится* — вторая часть имеет значение следствия.
(*Если используешь воображение, у тебя всё получится.*)

Иди смело вперёд, и у тебя всё получится!
Выбирай спорт, и у тебя всё получится!
Сумейте создать соответствующие условия, и вы удлините жизнь растений.

[Сложносочиненное предложение](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/284-slognosochinennoepredlogenie.html)

Думаю, что постановка запятой обязательна, а вот употребление тире вместо запятой — факультативно (все зависит от контекста и тех интонаций, которые нужно подчеркнуть автору).

"В предложениях с союзом ***и*** могут передаваться значения неожиданного результата, быстрой смены событий, такие предложения характеризуются особой, прерывистой интонацией. Например: *Один прыжок — и лев уже на спине буйвола* (Купр.); *Подложили огонь под готовый костер со стружками — и пламя запылало* (Акс.)" ([из учебника Н. С. Валгиной](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-040.htm)).