# Тире перед присоединительной частью предложения

Tags: пунктуация, тире, авторская-пунктуация

В предложении "Ипользуй воображение, и у тебя всё получится" вместо ли использование тире перед второй частью вместо запятой?

Comment: Повтор вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453928/Нужно-ли-тире-перед-союзом-и-в-данном-предложении

Comment: Пользуйтесь окном Поиска по сайту!

Comment: @sharon, очень не хватает вашей помощи...

Answer (score 1):

**(1) Используй воображение, и у тебя всё получится.**

Это сложносочиненное предложение (ССП), основное средство связи — **соединительный союз И.**

Но ССП бывают однородного и неоднородного состава.

В ССП **однородного состава** простые предложения полностью равноправны в смысловом отношении, ряд предложений открытый (его можно продолжить), интонация перечислительная, например: *Но тишина был нарушена. Хлопнула дверь, и в окнах зажегся свет, и собака залаяла во дворе.*

ССП **неоднородного состава** состоят из двух предложений, отношения между которыми неоднородны по смыслу, и тогда в ССП  могут дополнительно выражаться **причинные, условные и уступительные значения.** Для выражения этих значений используются **дополнительные средства.**

В данном предложении соединительный по форме союз И имеет **дополнительное условно-следственное значение,** которое выражено **разными  формами глагола**: императив в первой части и будущее время во второй части.

Примеры: ***Просите, и дано будет вам; ищите, и найдете.*** Синонимом такого ССП является СПП с союзом ЕСЛИ.

Таким образом, запятая здесь на месте, она является основным знаком, **обязательной подстановки тире не требуется.**

**(2) Используй воображение —  и у тебя всё получится.**

**А зачем тогда нужно тире?** Тире здесь  **авторское интонационное,** оно обозначает **увеличенную паузу**.

В этом случаемы мы как бы  копируем интонацию, которая в БСП является основным средством связи, сравнить: ***Будешь использовать воображение —  получишь нужный результат.***

Поэтому при использовании тире мы получаем **большую экспрессию:** то, что уже выражено грамматикой, дополнительно усиливается интонацией с тем же значением.

Comment: да, я всегда "за" авторского знака... Мне тоже по душе постановка тире, хотелось просто узнать, допустимо или нет. Чтобы потом в редакции не придирались. Спасибо вам огромное за подробное объяснение... только вы так объясняете

Answer (score 0):

Тире лучше, так как здесь следственная связь (результат). Также тире усиливает важность второго простого предложения. А это здесь уместно. С запятой смысл более пассивный.